# Why doesn't a Google chart resize properly inside an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to resize a Google chart on window resize.

Take a look at this jsFiddle [[link]](http:////jsfiddle.net/je8as7zc/)

There are 2 tables being drawn when this is run.

- chart1 is sitting outside of the table.
- chart2 is sitting inside a td in the table.

When you increase the width of the page, both charts resize appropriately.

When you decrease the width of the page, chart1 will resize appropriately but chart2 will remain at its maximum width.

A simple solution to this would be to avoid using the table in this situation.
But can anybody figure out why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Because the table will resize according to its contents. The table's contents won't resize according to the table. When you expand the table, the chart grows because there's room to fill. But once it's expanded its size takes priority over the table, so the table can't shrink it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I swapped out the table for an unordered list and it is working well now. Thanks for the reply